# VBA error adding a Name with a formula in the reference

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to add a `Name` to my workbook. The reference has an `INDEX` formula. I am getting an error on this line of code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Reference
```

I tried it with `ActiveWorkbook` and also tried defining a worksheet.

I guess it doesn't work, because the name range can not be matched with a worksheet because it has a function in it, but i do not know how to solve. Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
Sub NameRange_Add3()
Dim RangeName As String
Dim Reference As String
Dim i As Integer


For i = 2 To 6
    RangeName = "list" & i
    Reference = "=INDEX(tabla_1;;MATCH(" & "hszis" & i & ";hszi_list;0))"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Reference
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using creating formulas in VBA you need to use the English notation, which means points as decimal separators and commas as function argument separators.

You can either do what @brettdj did and use commas

```
Reference = "=INDEX(tabla_1,,MATCH(" & "hszis" & 1 & ",hszi_list,0))"
```

or use `RefersToLocal` instead of `RefersTo`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersToLocal:=Reference
```

I would prefer the first solution though because otherwise it could fail if you execute the macro on a machine with different language settings.

Answer (score 2):

I ran it with

`Reference = "=INDEX(tabla_1,MATCH(" & "hszis" & i & ",hszi_list,0))"`

and it worked. Suggest you try removing the bonus `;`

`Reference = "=INDEX(tabla_1;MATCH(" & "hszis" & i & ";hszi_list;0))"`

Comment: do you mean the bonus `;` ?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Reference